# Camera flash with Picamera2

Tags: camera, raspicam, picamera

Is it possible to have Picamera2 trigger a flash when taking a picture?

In an older version of my project I used a v2 camera module. I got flash working by creating a device overlay to define the flash GPIO and then setting `flash_mode` to `on` or `auto` for my `PiCamera` instance.

Now I have a v3 camera module and I'm trying to use Picamera2, but I can't find a flash-related setting to enable. It's the same with `libcamera-still`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [Raspberry Pi forums](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?p=2093211#p2093211) I was informed that this is not currently possible. I'm doing a sort-of work around by turning the LED on and off in code via GPIO. Basically I import `LED` from `gpio`, create an `LED` for the GPIO where the flash is attached, and then turn the LED on and off at the appropriate times.

Anyone who could use built-in support in Picamera2 should comment on the [Github issue](https://github.com/raspberrypi/picamera2/issues/635) I opened about this.